# How to add related aggregate data in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

One Metric model has many Measurements.

I've set up the relationship so I can do things like:

```php
$metrics = Metric::with('measurements' => function($query) {
   return $query->where('timestamp', '>=', '20190731');
});
```

This works to fetch all the measurements from 31 July 2019 for the metrics.

But what I want to achieve now is to fetch aggregated measurement data.

**EDIT: Here's a better explanation of what I'm after**

If the above gives something like:

```
results = [
  {          id: 1,
           name: 'Metric 1',
   measurements: [
        { id: 123, metric_id: 1, value: 4,  timestamp: 2019-07-31T09:00 },
        { id: 124, metric_id: 1, value: 10, timestamp: 2019-07-31T10:00 },
        ...
        { id: 124, metric_id: 1, value: 10, timestamp: 2019-08-01T09:00 },
                 ] },
  ...
]
```

Then what I want to achieve would result in this:;

```
results = [
  {          id: 1,
           name: 'Metric 1',
   measurementStats: [
        { metric_id: 1, period: 2019-07-31, min: 4, max: 10 },
        { metric_id: 1, period: 2019-08-01, min: 10, max: 10 },
                 ] },
  ...
]
```

I imagine that when eager loading, Eloquent should run something like this:

```
  SELECT metric_id,
         DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y%m%d') as period,
         MIN(value) AS min,
         MAX(value) AS max
    FROM measurements
   WHERE metric_id IN (...)
GROUP BY metric_id, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y%m%d')
```

Is there a way to achieve that in Eloquent/Laravel query builder? (Laravel 5.8)

Comment: Can you explain the sql query little bit, it would be easy to understand the requirement

Comment: @SagarGautam thanks for your time, I've expanded the question, is that clearer?

Comment: Yes it can be done, I did something similar.
You can review this page of the Laravel manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins, with that you can surely get it for yourself. You just have to put the pieces together.
Use example ```DB: raw ("DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y%M%d') as period")``` for complex queries.

Comment: @NewWorldNeverland I know I can do it if I abandon Eloquent, but was hoping to have something like `function measurementStats() { return $this->hasMany(...); }` so I could use eager loading?

Comment: @artfulrobot I have added my answer have a try

Comment: @artfulrobot, I hope you can solve it, I already looked for something similar to what you say, but I had to combine Eloquent with QueryBuilder to get what I wanted. Example: https://pastebin.com/MPz4qprD

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding new attribute to the model which is the average of the measurements.

Add following lines to you Metric Model.

```
protected $appends = array('min', 'max');

public function getMinAttribute()
{
    return $this->measurements()->where('timestamp', '>=', '20190731')->min('value');
}


public function getMaxAttribute()
{
    return $this->measurements()->where('timestamp', '>=', '20190731')->max('value');
}
```

Now, you can access min and max as normal model attributes,

```
foreach($metrics as $metric){
    // $metric->max
    // $metric->min
}
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this creates an N+1 efficiency issue and does not group by day?

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped to use Laravel's own eager loading but with a derived 'model' from my stats query, but I don't think this is possible; Laravel's eager loading is too tied to Eloquent models. However, I did find this solution:

### Changes to the Metric Model

We will:

1. Create a measurementStats attribute (a very long winded way of making a public property!)
2. Tell the model to use a custom collection instead of the normal Eloquent collection.
3. Tell the model to append the stats attribute when turning itself into JSON.

App/Metric.php:

```php
namespace App;

use App\MetricCollection;
...
class Metric
{
  ...

  protected $appends = ['measurementStats'];

  /** @var array */
  protected $measurementStats;

  public function getMeasurementStatsAttribute() {
    return $this->measurementStats ?? [];
  }

  public function setMeasurementStatsAttribute($stats) {
    $this->measurementStats = $stats;
  }

  public function newCollection(array $models=[]) {
    return new MetricCollection($models);
  }
```

### Custom collection

This will enable us to load all the measurement stats in one query and attach them to the models.

```php
namespace App;

  use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
  use \DB;

  class MetricCollection extends Collection
  {
    public function addMeasurementStats($filters) {
      $metric_ids = $this->modelKeys();
      $stats_query = DB::table('measurements')
        ->select('metric_id')
        ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y%m%d') as period")
        ->selectRaw("MIN(value) AS min")
        ->selectRaw("MAX(value) AS max")
        ->selectRaw("AVG(value) AS value")
        ->whereIn('metric_id', $metric_ids)
        ->groupBy('metric_id', 'period');

      if (!empty($filters['since'])) {
        $stats_query->where('timestamp', '>=', $filters['since']);
      }
      foreach ($stats_query->get()->groupBy('metric_id') as $metric_id => $stats) {
        $this->find($metric_id)->measurementStats = $stats;
      }
      return $this;
    }
  }
```

### Finally, fetch the metrics with stats

```php
$data = Metric::all()->addMeasrementStats(['since' => '2019-07-31']);
```